# paste data to adjacent cell if cell has value

Tags: excel, vba

https://i.postimg.cc/fRR8SnG2/Untitled.jpg

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A7:A" & lastRow + 1)
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        Range("H7:M7").Select
           Selection.Copy
           Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next cell
```

it is copying one row below were data is not present in g column

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: its copying 1 row extra.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/zvntm4vn/Untitled.jpg

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: extra row should not copy

Answer (score 0):

It copy an extra row because you start the comparing at row 7 but start inserting at row 8.
Just change the Range in rng from A7 to A8

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A8:A" & lastRow + 1)
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        Range("H7:M7").Select
           Selection.Copy
           Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
           Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next cell
```